# bash ls output to file when ls finds no results

Tags: linux, bash, shell, logging, ls

i'm relative new to scripting in bash, and made the following script:

```
# Set variables
logfile=/tmp/peter/logfile.log
indir=/mls/indir/IG/
tempdir=/mls/indir/IG/IGTEMP/
MLSready=/mls/indir/IG/MLSready

#Log current date/time
date >>$logfile

#Check whether processing files are present and one MLSready file exists. If not, exit the script.
if ls ${tempdir}R* 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then 
   mv $MLSready $tempdir
   if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
      echo MLSready move succeeded, copy processing files from $tempdir to $indir >>$logfile
      ls -l ${tempdir}MLSready >>$logfile
      find $tempdir -type f -name 'RPUO*' -mmin +1 -exec mv {} $indir \; 
      find $tempdir -type f -name 'RFRO*' -mmin +3 -exec mv {} $indir \; 
   else
      echo MLSready does not exist, exit script >>$logfile
      exit 1
   fi 
else
   echo no processing files in $tempdir, exit script >>$logfile
   exit 1
fi

echo set new MLSready file >>$logfile
# date >$MLSready
ls -l $MLSready 1>&2 >>$logfile

exit
```

At the end of the script, i don't make a new MLSready file.
When i execute the script, i expect to see the result of the latest 'ls -l' command in my logfile, however (because i didn't create a new MLSready file?) the output is redirected to my prompt instead of to my logfile:

```
DC3_igsy3ft3.sonic:/tmp/peter> ./move_bmp_files.sh
ls: 0653-341 The file /mls/indir/IG/MLSready does not exist.
```

How can i arrange that the result of the latest 'ls -l' command is always redirected to my logfile?

I also tried with:

```
ls -l $MLSready 2>&1 >>$logfile
ls -l $MLSready >>$logfile
```

Below my logfile:

```
do okt  6 09:22:39 2016
MLSready move succeeded, copy processing files from /mls/indir/IG/IGTEMP/ to /mls/indir/IG/
-rw-rw-rw-    1 oracle   505               0 okt 06 09:22 /mls/indir/IG/IGTEMP/MLSready
set new MLSready file
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the order:

```
$ ls -l $MLSready >>$logfile 2>&1
$
```

Comment: Great! That seems to do the trick!
I don't quite get it yet.. I want to redirect the error output to default output (with 2>&1) and then i want to log it.. 
Why does it work the other way around?

Comment: You first redirect your stdout to your logfile and then redirect your stderr to stdout as well, ie. everything outputted--good and bad--will be redirected to your logfile. Why the order? beats me, never bothered to think about it. :D